# Number of ways in which a number greater than $100$ and less than $4000$ can be formed from the integers $0,1,2,3,4$ if repetition is allowed.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of ways in which a number greater than $100$ and less than $4000$ can be formed from the integers $0,1,2,3,4$ if repetition is allowed.

i) For numbers between (100-999), For the hundreds place we have $4$ choices excluding zero and for the rest of them, there is a total of $5$ choices. So the total permutation is $4 \times 5 \times 5=100$.

ii) For numbers between (1000-3999), For the thousand place we have $3$ choices {1,2,3} and for the rest of them, there is a total of $5$ choices. so the total permutation is $3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5=375$.

My intuition was to do $375 \times 100=37500$. The reason being as the use of **AND** as it is less than $4000$ **AND** greater than $100$ due to which I thought both the cases are simultaneous.

But the correct answer was $375+100=475$. How is it a **OR**  case rather **How are both i) & ii) mutually exclusive**

**All perspectives are accepted.**

Comment: You can consider [1] as a $4$ digit string with $0$ allowed at the thousands place, whereas in [2], it is not allowed, so the two are disjoint.

Comment: consider (100,999) and (1000,3999) are disjoint sets. union will be (100,3999) and intersection is empty set. thus chooing numbers from each set and combine is addition not multiplication.

Comment: To rephrase the above comments, you divided the numbers into two mutually exclusive cases, three-digit positive integers in case i and four-digit positive integers in case ii.  Any number satisfying the requirement has either three digits or four digits.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the answer $37500$ is clearly wrong since there are only $3901$ integers between $100$ and $4000$. So even without knowing the correct answer, you can clearly see that your answer is not correct.

---

Let me first highlight your error with a caricature that makes the same error as you. Suppose you want to count the number of ways you can select a person that is both a grandparent of my son **and** lives east of my home.

Well, we have two possibilities. Either the grandparent is male or female.

1. If they are female, then they can either be Anne (my mother) or Betty (my partner's mother), but Anne lives west of me, so if they are female, there is only one option.
2. If they are male, then they can either be Charles (my father) or Doug (my partner's father), but Charles lives west of me, so if they are male, there is only one option.

So, one way to select a person if they are female, one if they are male, and given that the question says the person must be both a grandparent **and** live east of me, the end result is $1\cdot 1$ which is $1$.

Of course the result is wrong, but can you spot the error?

---

The problem is that yes, the conditions of the question use the word **and**, but that has no effect on how you are solving. For example, the question could equally be posed as "what is the number of ways in which an integer belonging to the set $[100,  4000]$ can be selected", in which case there is no "**and**" in the question!

Now, of course, there is a rule of thumb in combinatorics that basically says "when you say *or*, you make an addition, and when you say *and*, you make a multiplication", but that rule does not apply to the **question**, it applies to the **answer**. In your answer, you basically said this:

- Well, the number can be either smaller **or** greater than $1000$.
- If it is smaller then there are $100$ possibilities
- If it is greater, then there are $375$ possibilities.

Notice that there is an **or** in your solution, and it is that **or** that must tell you that you should add the two numbers, so long as the two possibilities separated by the *or* are mutually exclusive. Well, clearly "smaller than $1000$" and "greater than $1000$" are mutually exclusive, so we can add the two numbers and get $475$ posibilities.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$100_5=25 $ and $4000_5=500$
then the desired answer is
$500-25=475$